# Подскажите фреймворк чтобы распаковать gzip не используя стримы?

Tags: java, spring

Приложение на spring+java
Есть файл с расширением gzip, его требуется разархивировать и куда-то рядом положить.

Я нашел статью с готовым примером
[тут](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-file-from-gzip-file/)

Но есть ли аналоги в спринге, как это можно сделать красиво, не прибегаю к коддингу и работе со стримами?

Comment: а чем Вам потоки не угодили?

Comment: @Tsyklop да не знаю, смущает что-то. Есть же красивые фреймворки наверняка с удобным api